# Trying to set a new value to storage contract through another contract

Tags: solidity

I'm having a problem of setting a value to storage contract through another contract. Below is the code:

**StorageContract.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.8;

contract StorageContract {
    constructor () public {
       userStruct[msg.sender].userId = msg.sender;
       userStruct[msg.sender].userName = 'Jack';
       userStruct[msg.sender].isUser = true;
    }

    mapping(address => User) public userStruct;

    struct User {
        address userId;
        string userName;
        uint userRegistrationDate;
        bool isUser;
    }

    function setNewUser(address _userId, string memory _userName) public returns(address){
        require(userStruct[msg.sender].isUser == true, "Error (setNewUser)");
        User storage u = userStruct[_userId];
        u.userName = _userName;
        u.userRegistrationDate = now;
        u.isUser = true;
        return _userId;
    }
}
```

**UserContract.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.8;

import "./StorageContract.sol";

contract UserContract {
    StorageContract storages;
    constructor (address _storageAddress) public {
        storages = StorageContract(_storageAddress);
    }

    function userSetNewUser(address _userId, string memory _userName) public returns(address){
        require(msg.sender != address(0));
        address userId = storages.setNewUser(_userId, _userName);
        return userId;
    }
}
```

The problem I face here is that I cannot set a new user through `UserContract`, since it does not satisfy the `require` statement at `setNewUser` and I cannot understand why. Would highly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

When one contract calls another contract `msg.sender` is no longer the address who initiated the transaction originally but the `Caller Contract`.

In your case `msg.sender` in the `setNewUser` in `StorageContract` is `UserContract`. And since, you have not registered `UserContract` as user it cannot create new user.